# Block access to desktop

Tags: wpf, windows, security, c#-4.0, kiosk

I am developing a C# WPF application, which will feature various levels of security to restrict the users ability to interact with the system.

At certain lower levels of login privilege, I need to prevent access to Windows, in order to stop the operator messing with system settings.

I can set the application to run Full Screen, but you can still bypass this via ALT+TAB or by pressing the windows key to access the Taskbar.

What is the best way to achieve this? Can I write a handler to intercept ALT+TAB & use of the Windows key?

The target platform is probably going to be Windows XP, but ideally I would like a solution that also works on other variants of windows (Win 7, Win 2003).

Comment: IMHO the best way for your application would be going several levels lower and working with WinAPI and functions like `CreateWindow` directly. WPF is not designed for such kind of tasks.

Comment: It seems you're looking for the so-called "kiosk mode". See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/18879/how-to-lock-down-windows-xp-for-use-as-an-internet-kiosk) on serverfault.